# How to use eagle cad to design a square coil

Tags: eaglecad

I am working in a project to design a wireless charging device. I need to design a square coil and fabricate it on PCB but i have no idea to start with the software. Using the software, what should I do. 
Whether i just need to use the traces to form the square coil.

Comment: Do you have a specific requirement, for example, its inductance? Have you calculated the geometry of the coil?

Comment: I know exactly how many turns the coil should be. What embarrassing me is that how to use the software EAGLE CAD to achieve the requirement because i am not familiar with the software.

Comment: Approximately, how big is the whole coil, how many 'turns', and how wide are the tracks? Also are there any other components on the PCB?

Comment: Eagle is a schematic/PCB drawing tool. It has nothing to do with inductor design.

Comment: @venny I suggest you read the question a bit better. The OP is asking how to create a PCB-based coil (i.e. a coil made from traces) to wirelessly charge devices.

Comment: It sounded more like needing to design both a part and package to placed on a PCB, but I could see it interpreted either way. If it is designing the coil using PCB traces, Eagle is NOT the program to use for that. An inductor can be modeled using a long thin trace on a PCB, but you need a better program to figure out the length and width of the trace. Try something like Ansoft Designer.

Comment: If you want to know how to use eagle, I recommend you do the Eagle tutorial, carefully read the documentation (which I think very good), then ask more specific questions, either at the Eagle community, or here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've calculated parameters, I.e. Trace width, number of turns, width, height, layers, etc, then you just need the connector on a schematic and turn that into a board with one giant trace, shaped how you want. Watch out for issues with trace heating and current capacity, there've been issues with that on some square coils I've seen in the past.

If you need to calculate those parameters above, eagle is not the right software to do that in.